# Predefined variables for repository resource trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When a pipeline is triggered by a [repository resource trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-repositories) I need to be able to determine metadata about the triggering repository (such as repo name and branch).

It sounds like [these variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#variables) should be set during a pipeline run that was triggered by a repository resource; however, their values are blank when I do `echo $(resources.triggeringAlias)` or `env | sort` in a pipeline run that was triggered by a repository resource.

UPDATE: the predefined variables for `Build.Repository.Name` and `Build.SourceBranchName` now work as expected when used with a repository trigger. So, while I'm no longer in need of `resources.triggeringAlias` and `resources.triggeringCategory`, they still aren't working.

Comment: Here I found an open issue about `resources.triggeringAlias` variables. The issue has been reported to Docs team, you can follow the ticker there to get notifications if there's any update. (PS: I can reproduce same issue, not sure if there's something wrong with the doc or it's just the new feature needs some time to take effect). You can take my answer as workaround to achieve what you want, let me know if it helps :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Glad I'm not crazy! I'll mark your answer as the solution in lieu of the issue being fixed. Thanks!

Comment: FYI here's the link to the issue on msft docs github: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/9389

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to be able to determine metadata about the triggering
> repository (such as repo name and branch)

We can use `$(Build.Repository.Name)` and `$(Build.Repository.Uri)` to get repo name and repo uri.

And `$(Build.SourceVersion)` can be used to get CommitId, `$(Build.SourceBranch)` or `$(Build.SourceBranchName)` can be used to get branch info.

Just **note** we must also checkout the triggering repo to make above variables work to fetch the info of triggering repo, otherwise those variables will always represents the value of triggered repo:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: TheTriggeringRepo
```

**Some details:**

I have a triggering repo `PipelineA`, and the triggered repo `PipelineB`. `PipelineB`'s `azure-pipelines.yml` file:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: PipelineA
    type: git
    name: PipelineA
    trigger:
      - master
  
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: PipelineA
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo $(Build.Repository.Name)
      echo $(Build.SourceBranch)
```

So this pipeline will be triggered by both `PipelineA` repo and `PipelineB` repo.

When `PipelineB` repo has changes:

[image]

When `PipelineA` repo has changes:

[image]

It's clear the `$(Build.Repository.Name)` variable can work well to output the real trigger repo if we checkout both these two repos. So just make sure you checkout those triggering repos, then my variables above would work for you.

Comment: I validated that your workaround is successful (i.e. use normal predefined variables instead of `resources.triggeringAlias` and also checkout the triggering repo). Since the docs don't match what we're seeing, it seems like the actual solution would be to resolve this issue, but I'm marking your answer as the solution since it's a valid workaround in the meantime. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Also you can consider reporting this issue in our [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) so that product team would view it, hope it helps :)

Comment: Great idea. Report is here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207913/predefined-variables-for-repository-resource-trigg.html

Comment: The note fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: client-qa-deployment ## Resources.TriggeringAlias will be 'client-qa-deployment' if this resource gets triggered.
    source: benjose.dev-code
    trigger:
      stages:
      - client_deploy_qa

- stage: qa_smoketest
  displayName: Smoke Test on QA Environment
  condition: eq(variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias'], 'client-qa-deployment')
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  jobs:
  - job: TestQA
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, $(Resources.TriggeringAlias)!
      displayName: 'Running Smoke Test on QA Environment'
```

> Hello, client-staging-deployment!

I believe the above snippet will help you to understand the syntax and usage of *Resources.TriggeringAlias*. This variable will be helpful if we have multiple resources in the same pipeline and to find out which resource got trigged.

Comment: The issue was that it wasn't working back then when it was a new feature. Glad to hear it's working as expected now!